# invalid mount path: 'db' mount path must be absolute

Tags: docker, docker-compose, amazon-dynamodb

Following is my docker file :

> ```
> FROM amazon/dynamodb-local
> WORKDIR /home/dynamodblocal
> RUN mkdir ./db && chown -R 1000 ./db
> CMD ["-jar", "DynamoDBLocal.jar", "-dbPath", "./db", "-sharedDb"]
> VOLUME ["./db"]
> ```

Following is the docker compose file :

> ```
> version: "3.3" 
> services:   
> dynamodb:
> build:
>   context: .
>   dockerfile: dynamodb/Dockerfile
> container_name: email_dynamo
> ports:
>   - "8000:8000"
> volumes:
>   - dynamodb-local:/home/dynamodblocal/db   
> seed:
> image: amazon/aws-cli
> container_name: email_dynamo_seed
> links:
>   - dynamodb
> depends_on:
>   - dynamodb
> command: sh -c "~/seed/seed.sh"
> entrypoint: []
> volumes:
>   - ~/.aws:/root/.aws
>   - ./seed:/root/seed 
> volumes:   
>    dynamodb-local:
>     driver: local
> ```

When I try to run docker-compose up , getting the following error :

> Building with native build. Learn about native build in Compose here:
> https://docs.docker.com/go/compose-native-build/ Recreating
> 89162581ebc2_email_dynamo ... error
>
> ERROR: for 89162581ebc2_email_dynamo  Cannot create container for
> service dynamodb: invalid volume specification:
> '6cf8eb4d8edc2203adc35064b97ce90adc306c1e136a77a2e5e6203647564cd5:db:rw':
> invalid mount config for type "volume": invalid mount path: 'db' mount
> path must be absolute
>
> ERROR: for dynamodb  Cannot create container for service dynamodb:
> invalid volume specification:
> '6cf8eb4d8edc2203adc35064b97ce90adc306c1e136a77a2e5e6203647564cd5:db:rw':
> invalid mount config for type "volume": invalid mount path: 'db' mount
> path must be absolute ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the
> project.

Answer (score 2):

The path in VOLUME option must be an exists path in the container. In your case need to change `VOLUME ["./db"]` to this: `VOLUME ["/home/dynamodblocal/db"]`

And the **WORKDIR** sets the default directory only for **RUN**, **CMD**, **ENTRYPOINT**, **COPY** and **ADD** commands. **Not works with VOLUME!**

Comment: In my docker file , I have modified the last line to VOLUME ["/home/dynamodblocal/db"]. But I am still getting the same error .